# Read a table by indicating a pattern instead of the file name , using R

Tags: r

I have a folder with a LANDSAT image, with various files (tif, txt, etc).
I  read the metadata of the image (MTL file) and create a data frame from it, as follow:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Documents/L5__002072-09MAY-2006")
mtl <- read.delim(file="LT05_L1TP_002072_20060509_20161121_01_T1_MTL.txt",
                  sep = '=',
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
mtl
```

Is it possible to do the same, but instead of writing the name of the MTL file,  read the file of the folder with this pattern: "*MTL.txt"?

Comment: use `list.files` and `regex`

Comment: `read.delim(file=list.files(pattern=".*MTL.txt"), sep="=", stringsAsFactors = FALSE )`

Comment: The dot is a meta character so it should be escaped, `pattern=".*MTL\\.txt"`. Anyway, +1

Comment: or use `glob2rx("MTL.txt")`

Comment: Thank you! it works using both options (pattern=".*MTL.txt") or (pattern=".*MTL\\.txt")

Comment: If you think the pattern may *ever* match more than one file, you might want to iterate, perhaps `alldata <- lapply(list.files(pattern=".*MTL.txt"), read.delim, sep='=', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`. Once there, if you are *confident* that you'll have only one file, then do `mtl <- alldata[[1]]`, and you'll never fail. If you don't do this and there is ever another matching file, you'll get an `invalid 'description' argument` error, indicating the `file` argument is of length greater than 1.

Comment: Another safe-guard instead would be to do `files <- list.files(...)`, then verify `if (length(files) == 1L) { mtl <- read.delim(...); } else { stop("not exactly 1 file foudn"); }`. (This is all under the auspices of how I envision *defensive programming*, assuming that the user or the OS will try malevolently to foil your best intentions.)

Comment: Thank you r2evans!  I will have these points in mind

Answer (score 0):

This should work ::

```
read.delim(file=list.files(pattern=".*MTL.txt"), sep="=", stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
```